# TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. Using in Object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, object

So I have this function:

```
export default function getObjectFromTwoArrays(keyArr: Array<any>, valueArr: Array<any>) {
  // StartPoint:
  //  [key1,key2,key3],
  //  [value1,value2,value3]
  //
  // EndPoint: {
  //  key1: value1,
  //  key2: value2,
  //  key3: value3
  // }

  if (keyArr.length === valueArr.length) {
    // @ts-ignore
    return Object.assign(...keyArr.map((el,index) => ({[el]: valueArr[index]})))
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Arrays should be the same length: ${{keyArr}}, ${{valueArr}}`)
  }
}
```

So me need to get exact this result from example above - EndPoint.
I tried to expand to a variable, got the same issue.

I tried to to replace with: `Object.assign({...keyArr.map((el,index) => ({[el]: valueArr[index]}))})`

But the result will be: `{0: {key1: value1}, 1: {key2: value2}}`

Also with `Object.assign([...keyArr.map((el,index) => ({[el]: valueArr[index]}))])`

Result: `[{key1: value1}, {key2: value2}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Object.assign` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) takes at least one parameter, but in your function the array you were spreading could have been empty. The key part in the error message is "*must be passed to a rest parameter*", and from [the various overload signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c333e14578984d0071da63fc28147f1e6fc43ae0/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L260-L293) the one you'd want to use is `assign(target: object, ...sources: any[]): any;`. To avoid the need for `// @ts-ignore`, you'd write

```
return Object.assign({}, ...keyArr.map((el,index) => ({[el]: valueArr[index]})))
//                   ^^^
```

<sup>([Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA29noHYDGMAlhHnAObAwDyARgFbBEBiUEAtgCoDuEAglCioAngGcAFAGtgIwVABcceaIA8qPCIB8AGjgA3VJnTB5SlSPWatASjgBvAFBw4xZHGmz5AOkzA8FDAAFnAAvOEGRiY+fgHBdk4uLlDU6FDk9ExE3qhiYsQUeBL2AL563hUyckLeHKhgEhLAmDrEeEggdqFaHvYA2s0AukqGxqZCfW0dgyU2c85wJXDNYsAOCy7B7DxweMA7AKJC0BIABhZicGJBEFgIcHRrwWtiqBxrsYFBSgAk9vZVeQlMpwP72UbRITA042BYlRwlIA))</sup>

However, you really should not use `Object.assign` for this. What you want is `Object.fromEntries`, which takes an iterable of tuples:

```
export default function getObjectFromTwoArrays(keyArr: Array<any>, valueArr: Array<any>) {
  if (keyArr.length === valueArr.length) {
    return Object.fromEntries(keyArr.map((key, index) => [key, valueArr[index]]))
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Arrays should be the same length: ${{keyArr}}, ${{valueArr}}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of your parameters it looks like you're trying to take an array of keys and an array of values and turn it into an object. But `Object.assign` takes *two* parameters: a [source and a target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Neither of which should be an array. You want `Object.fromEntries`, but first you need to combine the two arrays into a single array of key/value pairs:

```
const zip = (xs, ys) => {
  if (xs.length === ys.length) {
    return xs.map((x, i) => [x, ys[i]]);
  } else {
    throw new Error('cannot merge arrays of unequal length');
  }
};

const getObjectFromTwoArrays = (keys, values) => Object.fromEntries(zip(keys, values));
```

The `Object.fromEntries` method takes an array of key/value pairs and turns it into an object, it is the converse of `Object.entries`. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: reduce is overused `return xs.map((x, i) => [x, ys[i]])`

Comment: "*`Object.assign` takes two parameters*" - no, it takes arbitrary many objects